# Can I use get request instead of post request in HTTPS? in mobile development

Tags: security, post, https, get, url-parameters

I'm developing an mobile app, which I have already add a self-sign certificate in it. I get all data by https method. And I found I can't use Charles to attack my data.

Is that mean I can set client password as part of https url parameter? Is this safe?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Check out this post on how to ask a question that is more likely to get an answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the query portion of the HTTPS URL is encrypted it is not safe.

HTTPS does not encrypt the entire host portion of the URL, the host portion of the URL is used by the network to direct to the other system. Everything other than the host portion is encrypted including any query, etc.

But note that many servers log the entire URL including the query and this represents a security vulnerability. Thus it is best to put sensitive information in the POST body.

Comment: I am using post request, but according to our web service, we put data in url of post, the request still post, but data is on url, not in body. Is there any difference between sensitive information in body and in url of post request?

Comment: When using HTTPS everything except the host portion is encrypted so the path and attribute including the query string are encrypted. Example: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45822216/can-i-use-get-request-instead-of-post-request-in-https-in-mobile-development/45822637?noredirect=1#comment78813191_45822637` Only `stackoverflow.com` is not encrypted, all the rest is encrypted. Note that the server may include the entire URL in its logs.

Answer (score -1):

yes **https** encrypt everything including url so you are free to use parameters in your url

https works between tcp and http and encrypt everything however its not a good idea to put confidential information in url because browser history or dns can still leak the information

Comment: Of course HTTPS does **not** encrypt the entire URL, the host portion of the URL is used by the network to direct to the other system, the rest is encrypted. But there are reasons not to put sensitive information in the URL query string.